# Dynamically create unique ID for an array of input fields using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array of dates. 
The code below loops over the dates to print out an the dates with text fields. 
What I'm trying to do is create an array of text fields which has unique ID's.
Then pass each dates with its array text field (values) into a php script.

Any ideas?

```
  for (var i in dates) {
    var d = dates[i];

    if (d) { // sometimes the date is not actually selected, that's why we need to check.
        var length = 12;
        var str = i+d;
        var myUniqueTime = str.substring(0,length);
        myUniqueTime = myUniqueTime.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');


        times= ["<input type=\"text\" id=\""+i+"\" size=\"8\" name=\""+i+"\" onChange=\"changeTimeTo24Hrs()\" value=\""+i+"\" />", "<input type=\"text\" id=\"times\" size=\"8\" name=\"times\" value=\""+i+"\" />"];

      // OK, selected.  Fill an input field.  Or something.  Just for example,
      // we will display all selected dates in the element having the id "output".
      el.innerHTML += "I = " + i + "<br />" + times + "<br />" + d.print("%A, %Y %B %d") + " <font size='-1'>" + myUniqueTime + "</font><br /><BR />";

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give all your text fields the name: `name ="dateField[]"`
then on the PHP side you will have an array of dateFields in your `$_POST` variable.

That is after submitting the form your `$_POST['dateField']` will look like this: `$_POST['dateField'] = array('date 1...', 'date 2...', 'date 3...');`

EDIT:

If you have a form:

```
<form method="post" action="formHandler.php">
  <input type="text" name="dateField[]" value="some date"/>
  <input type="text" name="dateField[]" value="some other date"/>
</form>
```

And you submit that form then the php file formHandler.php (specified by action="formHandler.php") will be called.  In formHandler.php you can work with the dates that were submitted.

formHandler.php:

```
echo 'First date: ' . $_POST['dateField'][0];
echo 'Second date: ' . $_POST['dateField'][1];
```

Comment: okay if i wanted to add a new text field using javascript; any ideas?

Comment: Oh and how do I make it post from the JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: I have tried everything and its still now working. Could you please edit my code so i know where to put the PHP post. I'm really struggling to do this.

Comment: Hi Mlaw. Thanks for your help. I sort of give up. It's not working. The problem is that dates are retrieved dynamically without a form - So i place a text field with the output. I really cant make the java script post the results. Thanks for your help again. I'm sort of new to php and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
  textbox = document.createElement('input');
  textbox.type = 'text';
  textbox.id   = i;
  el.appendChild(textbox);
}
```

You should bookmark w3schools.com for the javascript api. This is an easy thing to reference rather then have to ask a question.

Comment: Any ideas how to pass the array of dates and the array of text fields into a php? I have tried everything but it didn't work. so it should be like so: `date1 [value1, value2, value3]; date2 [value1, value2]`